# How to properly write api which need to work with complex objects (retreive, create, update methods)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to provide ability of working with a list of simple objects via api using django rest framework.

Considering using postgres as db in django, I used ArrayField for this purpouse:

```py
class QA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, default='')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    questions = postgres_fields.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1024), null=True, blank=True)
    answers = postgres_fields.ArrayField(models.TextField(), null=True, blank=True)

class QASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QA
        exclude = ()
```

For this code I can use following json for inserting a new `QA` object:

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "questions": ["123", "456", "789"],
    "answers": ["answer1", "answer2"]
}
```

It would be enough for resolving my problem, but I have to specify depended objects via another model using `ForeignKeyField`:

```py
class QA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, default='')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    qa = models.ForeignKey(QA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    qa = models.ForeignKey(QA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the first case, simple `ModelSerializer` would be a good solution, but I've got stuck with the case of using `ForeignKey` for binding many objects to one.

Does `django-rest-framework` provide an interface for retrieving, creating and patching objects via simple json, like I wrote in my question? What base class should I use in views and serializers? What methods should I overload for ability of interacting with a simple json, not creating another api for each model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is answered in the DRF Docs across many articles, but you should start [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) for basic serialization creation, and [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for writing nested serializers (to create multiple associated instances).